# Regular Expressions: Where to start

Tags: regex

When learning regular expressions, where would you start?  I am looking for a good set of things to learn so I can build a good base.  I don't expect to know everything from memory, but if I could learn the correct things - and enough of them - I could have a good head start on this.

Please give me your suggestions so I can have an efficient start to learning regexpressions.

Comment: Please review the [faq]. Questions generally revolve around code, and issues with it. Additionally regular expressions are varied depending on the language in use, which makes this question far too vague and open ended to be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Start and end here: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

Answer (score 2):

I learned the Regex I know in this website:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

It's really informative, and easy to understand, and most importantly, free! It was made by a Regex expert so there's nothing to fear. :)

Comment: This one is good too! +1

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the upvote! :) Just starting out and it's kinda hard to make comments without 50 rep. lol

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I learnt Regex(python regex) from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

For Regex testing, I primarily use [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com), it allows you to quickly check a regular expression against a block of text to see what it removes. It also supports grouping, which is very useful for testing applications.

While there are several conventions for Regular Expressions, the most common is perl-style, used by Perl, Python, Ruby, and more.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can follow c syntax documentation, then I'd highly recommend the unix man pages from "ed" program, which are also available on the net if you don't have access to unix/linux. This is where all the regex variants (for various programming languages) started. Once you swalled it you'll be able to easily apply yourself to any variant.
"man ed" on unix/linux, read the regular expressions part. Or search for "man ed" on google.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are actually implemented by DFA, deterministic finite automata and can mathematically be described as non-deterministic finite automata as well. These models are very simple and I think you only need to learn the basics to get the logic behind it:

We have an alphabet of symbols A, e.g. A = { a,b } or in a real application a lot of different characters e.g. UTF-8. Then we have nodes in a graph, where one is the start node.

These nodes can be connected using transitions that consume one character of input and then we go to a new node (or the same node).

So lets say we want a regular expression that takes 3 a and then 1 b for a match, it can be viewed as the following DFA:

```
start-> () -a-> () -a-> () -a-> () -b-> end
```

If we allow loops then we get the following type of regexp a* we can stay in the same node by consuming an a. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

I don't think it is smart to get bogged down in implementation details of different programming languages and text encoding. It is best to understand the logic first, then the rest is just details.

I would compare starting with e.g. pythons regex docs before learning the theory to starting to do integration by parts in mathematica without knowing about calculus, it will seem like magic, but in reality it is not very hard, rather it is very elegant and fun to learn and understand!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for regex is generally consistent between programming languages. But they vary in implementation from language to language. Mastering Regular Expression mentioned by ridgerunner is a good starting point.